# FQL to get Online Friends return zero

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to get Online Friends by using following code.

```
    protected void GetActiveFriends()
{
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");

    var uId = myInfo.id;

    dynamic friends = fb.Query("SELECT uid, name, pic_small, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

        Response.Write(friends.Count);

    foreach (dynamic friend in friends)
    {
        Response.Write(friend.id);
    }
}
```

friends.Count returns Zero & none of the friend.id gets displayed.

I guess my query is right then what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind got it. Had not added extra permissions.

Comment: I am having the same issue...could you please explain how to solve this issue....